# Embed [src]="src" no funciona en Angular 7, url insegura

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, pdf

Estoy intentando crear un visor de PDFs en Angular pero al pasarle la variable da error.
¿Me echáis una mano, por favor?

HTML:

```
<embed [src]="selectedFile" class="p-col-12" style="height: 800px;">
```

TS:

```
  private pathFiles = [
    'src/assets/pdf/test.pdf',
    'src/assets/pdf/test2.pdf',
    'src/assets/pdf/test3.pdf',
  ];
  constructor() {
    public selectedFile = this.pathFiles[0];
  }
```

Gracias.
Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da? Por cierto, te sobra el `src/`inicial de las URL, las url a los assets no necesitan más que `assets/...`

Comment: Hola!
Gracias por la ayuda, el error es: 
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando el servicio `DomSanitizationService`:

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

// ...

constructor(private sanador: DomSanitizationService) {
    public selectedFile = sanador.bypassSecurityTrustUr(this.pathFiles[0]);
}
```

Por motivos de seguridad, `[src]` solo funcionara si aseguras la url para evitar url con informacion malisiona y eso es lo que hace  `bypassSecurityTrustUr()`